# STM32H7 PWM with DMA not working properly

Tags: digital-logic, stm32, pwm, timer

I'm using the PWM mode within the TIM15_CH1 hardware to create a varying pulse width modulation to run the ws2812B (LED Light strip).

Current setup right now is that I have a buffer of pre-calcuated PW (Pulse Width) values that get transferred via DMA into the TIM15->CCR1 register. The DMA is configured to run in one shot mode, meaning after the DMA has transfer all of the data from the buffer into CCR1 its done.

CCR1 register is used to vary the duty cycle in PWM mode (DC = CCR1/ARR).

Issue occurring right now is

1. the PWM doesnt output all the PW values in the buffer. For example if the buffer has a length of 2 it will only output the first value.

ARR = 0x12B = 299
TIMERS are running on a 240MHz.

CODE:

Timer Initiation

```
/*
 * Timer_Driver.c
 *
 *  Created on: Jan. 8, 2021
 *      Author: Christopher
 */


#include "Timer.h"

void init_Timer(uint16_t * RGB_Array) {

    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_TIM15EN;

    GPIOA->MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE2;
    GPIOA->MODER |=  GPIO_MODER_MODE2_ALT;

    GPIOA->OSPEEDR &= ~GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED2;
    GPIOA->OSPEEDR |=  GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED2_VERY_HIGH;

    GPIOA->AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL2;
    GPIOA->AFR[0] |=  GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL2_TIM15;

    TIM15->CCMR1 &= ~TIM_CCMR1_CC1S;
    TIM15->CCMR1 |=  TIM_CCMR1_CC1S_OUTPUT_MODE;

    TIM15->CCMR1 &= ~TIM_CCMR1_OC1M;
    TIM15->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_PWM1;

    TIM15->ARR = 0x12B;
    TIM15->PSC = 0x00;
    TIM15->CCR1 = 0x00;
    TIM15->AF1 &= ~TIM15_AF1_BKINE;
    TIM15->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE;
    TIM15->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_ARPE;
    TIM15->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_URS;
    //TIM15->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_OPM;
    TIM15->DIER |= TIM_DIER_UDE;


    //TIM15->CCMR1 &= ~TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE;

    TIM15->BDTR |= TIM_BDTR_MOE;
    TIM15->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E;
    //TIM15->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;

    RCC -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;


             DMAMUX1_Channel2 -> CCR |= DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID_TIM15_CH1;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Low;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_16BIT;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_16BIT;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
            // DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_M_TO_P;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_TCIE;

             DMA1_Stream2 -> NDTR = 4;

             DMA1_Stream2 -> PAR = (int) &TIM15->CCR1;
             DMA1_Stream2 -> M0AR = (int) RGB_Array;

             //DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;


}
```

Where the Timer and DMA gets started:

```
uint16_t GREEN [4] = {150, 150, 150, 150};

void setLedLights(uint8_t color, uint16_t * RGB_Array) {

if (color == 1) {


    memcpy(RGB_Array, GREEN, sizeof(uint16_t) * 4);
    TIM15->CCR1 = RGB_Array[0];



} else if (color == 2) {

    memcpy(RGB_Array, RED, sizeof(uint16_t) * 25);
    TIM15->CCR1 = RGB_Array[0];





} else if (color == 3) {

    memcpy(RGB_Array, BLUE, sizeof(uint16_t) * 25);
    TIM15->CCR1 = RGB_Array[0];


}

DMA1_Stream2 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

TIM15->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;


}


void DMA1_Stream2_IRQHandler(void) {

  if (((DMA1 -> LISR) & (DMA_LISR_TCIF2)) != 0) {
      DMA1 -> LIFCR |= DMA_LIFCR_CTCIF2;
      TIM15->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;

  }
}
```

Picture:
[image]

With the array of RGB_Array[4] = {150,150,150,150}
As you can see I have 4 values, the TIM only outputted 3.

Comment: From my point of view, there are more than 3 values output, perhaps 4.

Comment: I'm havign same problem... did you find some solution?

Comment: I see inverted PWM with 4 pulses on the picture.